# WebComponent nested CSS is invalid

Tags: css, web-component

After my testing, it is effective to write css directly using nesting, but in WebComponent, it is invalid after nesting with :host selector. The following is the demo code, My Chrome version number is 117

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/index.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template class="template_testCom">
      <style>
        :host {
          width: 200px;
          height: 50px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          font-weight: 700;
          background-color: #c00;

          & .container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70%;
            background-color: #fcf;
            & .text {
              color: #fff;
            }
          }
        }
      </style>

      <div class="container">
        <span class="text">textContent</span>
      </div>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import TestCom from "/TestCom.js";
window.customElements.define("test-com", TestCom);
const com_testCom = new TestCom();
document.body.append(com_testCom);
```

TestCom.js

```
class TestCom extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.#init();
  }
  #init() {
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    const ele_templateTestCom = document.querySelector(".template_testCom");
    const content = ele_templateTestCom.content.cloneNode(true);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(content);
  }
}

export default TestCom;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc78H.png)

The following is a test, when non-WebComponent uses CSS nesting, the styles within CSS nesting are in normal use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .noWebComponent {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: #c00;

        & .container {
          display: flex;
          width: 100%;
          height: 70%;
          background-color: #fcf;
          & .text {
            color: #fff;
          }
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="noWebComponent">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text">textContent</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae7Am.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

##### Nested CSS can **not** cross shadow boundaries.

`:host` (yellow) ***references* the Web Component itself**, not the shadowDOM inside

[image]

.

So your non-Web-Component code that works for you (green),
should be copied 1:1 to the shadowDOM to apply your *nested* CSS on a DOM node ***inside*** shadowDOM (blue)

```html
<style id="STYLE">
  .wrapper {
    width: 200px; height: 50px;
    display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: brown;
    & .container {
      background-color: grey;
      & .text {
        color: gold;
      }
    }
  }
</style>

<b>DOM, no shadowRoot:</b>
<div class="wrapper" id="WRAPPER">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text">textContent</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  customElements.define("text-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        .innerHTML = `<style>${STYLE.innerHTML}</style>` + WRAPPER.outerHTML;
    }
  });
</script>
<b>Web Component:</b>
<text-component></text-component>
```

Note: you can do it with `:host` and without the `.wrapper` DIV. But you can not use nested styles **accross** shadowRoot boundaries. So code needs to become:

```css
  :host {
    width: 200px; height: 50px;
    display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: brown;
   }
   .container {
      background-color: grey;
      & .text {
        color: gold;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: very thanks, I got it ~